# React Component does not render when clicking CardActionArea from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm running into a weird issue that I've never run into before.

I'm using Material UI components, specifically `CardActionArea` paired with 
 `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

Upon clicking the `CardActionArea` I want to redirect my users to a detail screen of the component they just clicked.

The detail view *sometimes* renders and *sometimes* it doesn't. For example, if I click on the `CardActionArea` the detail view *does not* render, but if I navigate directly to the URL, the detail view *does* render.

This is the relevant code:

```
// Dashboard.js
return (
  <Grid container spacing={40} className={classes.root}>
    <TopMenu></TopMenu>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/v/:videoId" component={VideoDetail} />
    </Router>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={(YouTubeVideoGallery)} />
    </Router>
  </Grid>
);
```

The CardActionArea is here:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirect: false
    };
    this.handleCardActionClick = this.handleCardActionClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleCardActionClick = () => {
    this.setState({redirect: true});
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const date = moment(this.props.video.publishedAt);
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (<Redirect to={`/dashboard/v/${this.props.video.id}`} />)
    }

    return (
      <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea onClick={this.handleCardActionClick}>
        <CardHeader
          title={
            (this.props.video.title.length > 21) ?
              this.props.video.title.substr(0, 18) + '...' :
              this.props.video.title
            }
          subheader={`${date.format('MMMM DD[,] YYYY')} - Views: ${this.props.video.viewCount}`}
        />
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={this.props.video.thumbnails.medium.url}
          title={this.props.video.title}
          />
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
    );
  }
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First thing handleCardActionClick is an arrow function so you no need to do binding in constructor. That can be removed

To redirect on onclick do something like below

```
 render(){
   const url = `/dashboard/v/${this.props.video.id}`;
   return(
      <div>
         {this.state.redirect && <Redirect to={url} />}
      </div>
   )
 }
```